# Determine the probability conditional on an event

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with density function

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
    0.2 & \text{if } -1 < x \leq 0 \\
    0.2 + cx & \text{if } 0 < x \leq 1 \\
    0 & \text{another case}
\end{cases}
$$

As $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx =1$ we know that the value of $c =\frac{6}{5}$ and as the cumulative distribution fuction is given by $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x)dx$ then

$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 & x<-1 \\
    \int_{-1}^{x}(0.2)dt & \text{if } -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
    \int_{0}^{x}(0.2+\frac{6t}{5})dt & \text{if } 0 < x < 1 \\
    1 & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

I want to find the following probability

$$P(X > 0.5 | X > 0.1)$$

I know the definition of conditional property, which in this case is

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$

But I don't see how to relate this to find the result, any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to plug in the definitions. Take $A=\{ X>0.1 \}$ and $B=\{ X>0.5 \}$.

Then $A\cap B=B$. Density function means that  $P(X\in A)= \int_A f dx$.
Using the density function, you get that

$$ P(A)= \int_{\frac{1}{10}}^1\big( \frac{1}{5}+cx \big)dx \quad \text{and} \quad P(B)= \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\big( \frac{1}{5}+cx \big)dx.$$

Just compute these sizes.